# Perovskite Optimization does not converge using gaussian

Tags: density-functional-theory, gaussian, geometry-optimization, perovskites

I am trying to optimize the geometry of (C5H14N2)[CuCl4] using g09. However, the calculation is not converging at any level of theory in 250 cycles. I am new to this field and I think I have made a serious mistake with this structure. here is my input file

```
# opt pm6
 scf=(tight,noincfock,novaracc,maxcycle=250)

 Title Card Required

0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
Cu(Fragment=4)     0.62103285    7.44978542    4.73411720
Cl(Fragment=4)     0.64538745    5.31663924    5.47586345
Cl(Fragment=4)     0.62509283    8.16087851    6.90430314
Cl(Fragment=4)     0.65868548    9.60132385    4.04814493
Cl(Fragment=4)     0.59879168    6.72458646    2.59526409
N(Fragment=6)     -0.27473404    3.44967132   10.97721414
H(Fragment=6)     -0.97947170    2.95052692   11.26414189
H(Fragment=6)      0.48331453    3.05081973   11.28551493
N(Fragment=6)      0.58340804    5.65159919    8.75294034
H(Fragment=6)     -0.24688321    5.74007440    8.39049213
H(Fragment=6)      1.17308410    6.00559408    8.15662767
C(Fragment=6)     -0.37544999    4.79286456   11.59672265
H(Fragment=6)     -1.22894013    5.20213883   11.30732878
C(Fragment=6)      0.69793915    5.72385264   11.30126475
H(Fragment=6)      1.55006623    5.22050782   11.31498924
C(Fragment=6)      0.62933920    6.49183944    9.98719190
H(Fragment=6)     -0.17527040    7.06737502   10.00271535
H(Fragment=6)      1.41924360    7.08568131    9.93049496
C(Fragment=6)      0.87377888    4.19571564    8.86254569
H(Fragment=6)      1.69183611    4.07127043    9.40554490
H(Fragment=6)      1.05478929    3.83524771    7.95782501
C(Fragment=6)     -0.24973338    3.40892100    9.48443692
H(Fragment=6)     -1.11018239    3.76097242    9.14364768
H(Fragment=6)     -0.17590003    2.46564513    9.19413762
Cu(Fragment=1)     2.48247578   14.20279790    7.77706647
Cu(Fragment=3)     3.66909961    8.22341458    7.17950788
Cu(Fragment=2)     2.76609907    0.38681458   10.69092973
Cl(Fragment=1)     2.45812119   12.06965172    7.03532023
Cl(Fragment=3)     3.64474501   10.35656076    6.43776163
Cl(Fragment=2)     2.79045367    2.51996076   11.43267598
Cl(Fragment=2)     0.51726582    0.34041772   10.89511005
Cl(Fragment=3)     3.66503963    7.51232149    5.00932194
Cl(Fragment=1)     4.73130904   14.24919476    7.57288616
Cl(Fragment=2)     2.74174447   -1.74633160    9.94918348
Cl(Fragment=3)     3.63144698    6.07187615    7.86548015
Cl(Fragment=1)     2.50819803   16.29268259    8.63311180
Cl(Fragment=1)     2.50471695   13.47759894    9.91591958
Cl(Fragment=3)     3.69134078    8.94861354    9.31836099
Cl(Fragment=2)     2.74385791    1.11201354    8.55207662
N(Fragment=5)      0.63483273   11.28627132    6.89322347
N(Fragment=8)      4.56486650   12.22352868    0.93641093
N(Fragment=7)      3.65529973    4.38692868    5.02040161
H(Fragment=5)      1.33957038   10.78712692    6.60629572
H(Fragment=8)      5.26960415   12.72267308    0.64948318
H(Fragment=7)      2.95056208    4.88607308    5.30732935
H(Fragment=5)     -0.12321584   10.88741973    6.58492268
H(Fragment=8)      3.80681793   12.62238027    0.62811014
H(Fragment=7)      4.41334830    4.78578027    5.32870240
N(Fragment=5)     -0.22330935   13.48819919    9.11749727
N(Fragment=8)      3.70672442   10.02160081    3.16068473
N(Fragment=7)      4.51344181    2.18500081    2.79612781
H(Fragment=5)      0.60698189   13.57667440    9.47994549
H(Fragment=8)      4.53701566    9.93312560    3.52313295
H(Fragment=7)      3.68315056    2.09652560    2.43367959
H(Fragment=5)     -0.81298542   13.84219408    9.71380995
H(Fragment=8)      3.11704835    9.66760592    3.75699741
H(Fragment=7)      5.10311787    1.83100592    2.19981513
C(Fragment=5)      0.73554867   12.62946456    6.27371496
C(Fragment=8)      4.66558244   10.88033544    0.31690243
C(Fragment=7)      3.55458378    3.04373544    5.63991011
H(Fragment=5)      1.58903881   13.03873883    6.56310883
H(Fragment=8)      5.51907258   10.47106117    0.60629629
H(Fragment=7)      2.70109364    2.63446117    5.35051624
H(Fragment=5)      0.78233501   12.51301268    5.29147232
H(Fragment=7)      3.50779744    3.16018732    6.62215276
C(Fragment=5)     -0.33784046   13.56045264    6.56917287
C(Fragment=8)      3.59219331    9.94934736    0.61236033
C(Fragment=7)      4.62797292    2.11274736    5.34445221
H(Fragment=8)      2.74006623   10.45269218    0.59863583
H(Fragment=5)     -0.37719554   14.22214380    5.83351843
H(Fragment=7)      4.66732800    1.45105620    6.08010664
C(Fragment=5)     -0.26924051   14.32843944    7.88324571
C(Fragment=8)      3.66079326    9.18136056    1.92643317
C(Fragment=7)      4.55937297    1.34476056    4.03037936
H(Fragment=5)      0.53536908   14.90397502    7.86772226
H(Fragment=8)      4.46540285    8.60582498    1.91090972
H(Fragment=7)      3.75476338    0.76922498    4.04590282
H(Fragment=5)     -1.05914491   14.92228131    7.93994265
H(Fragment=8)      2.87088886    8.58751869    1.98313012
H(Fragment=7)      5.34927737    0.75091869    3.97368242
C(Fragment=5)     -0.51368020   12.03231564    9.00789192
C(Fragment=8)      3.41635357   11.47748436    3.05107938
C(Fragment=7)      4.80381266    3.64088436    2.90573316
H(Fragment=8)      2.59829634   11.60192957    2.50808018
H(Fragment=5)     -0.69469061   11.67184771    9.91261261
H(Fragment=8)      3.23534316   11.83795229    3.95580007
H(Fragment=7)      4.98482306    4.00135229    2.00101247
C(Fragment=5)      0.60983207   11.24552100    8.38600069
C(Fragment=8)      4.53986584   12.26427900    2.42918815
C(Fragment=7)      3.68030039    4.42767900    3.52762438
H(Fragment=5)      1.47028107   11.59757242    8.72678994
H(Fragment=8)      5.40031485   11.91222758    2.76997740
H(Fragment=7)      2.81985138    4.07562758    3.18683514
H(Fragment=5)      0.53599871   10.30224513    8.67629999
H(Fragment=8)      4.46603248   13.20755487    2.71948746
H(Fragment=7)      3.75413374    5.37095487    3.23732508
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a periodic calculation? It looks cluster-based. Generally using small clusters as approximations for perovskite materials is not working.

Comment: @Greg can you suggest how could I make it a periodic calculation using gaussian? and should I use HF first and then move to DFT?

Comment: I have no experience using gaussian for periodic calculation, neither think it is the right tool for it. HF is definitely a big no-no for exploration of periodic systems. Your calculation seem to be semiempitical. Why do not you try semi-empirical periodic calculations first? xTB generally gives a good first guess for hybrid perovskites. What properties do you want to calculate?

Comment: @Greg I am trying to calculate the electronic structure and I also was trying optimization calculation using HF but it did not converge. The goal is to use DFT but I was trying my luck with a more simple level of theory. The fact is I do not know how to determine the number of k-points for this calculation

Comment: You should have more specific goals; you shouldn't do HF on periodic solids, it is not more simple neither helpful (only in very special cases); and the input you show is not HF, but PM6, a semiempirical method. The k points in practice can be determined based on what accuracy need / what property you want to calculate. For exploration / figure out how the software works gamma-point calculations are perfectly fine.

Comment: I recommend you to start from a CIF file with the crystallographic information. Then, use something like CIF2Cell tool to create an input for a DFT code. I suggest to use SIESTA like it is faster and less hardware resource eater than other (very)useful codes like Abinit/QuantumEspresso. From the CIF, you can use the symmetry info and use the main reference from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone) to generate the k path.

Comment: Since your only SE account is MMSE and you haven't logged into it in 3 months, which is 75% of your account's age, I'm flagging this question as "abandoned", but feel free to write a comment if you do see this, and we'll re-open it!